# How do you disable the iPhone keyboard Go button when a textfield is focused inside a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, soft-keyboard

One the screens within my app shows a UIWebView with a HTML web form. Currently when a textfield is focused and the keyboard appears a Go button is shown. Currently I have no user for the Go button and clicking it does nothing.

How can this button be disabled or removed, or how can I change the keyboard that is showing in a UIWebView?

Comment: you mean the textfield in the web page or in your page outside the webView?

Comment: Sorry from your title it seems the textField is inside UIWebView..

Answer (score 2):

I think the only option you have is to register for a call back when keyboard will show and get a UIView reference to the keyboard and add a Disabled looking Go button over the Actual Go Button in the keyboard.

1) First register for keyboardWillshow notification..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

2) IN your keyboardWillShow function traverse through all subViews of app window to get a reference to keyboard..

```
UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

UIView* keyboard;

//Iterate though each view inside of the selected Window
for(int i = 0; i < [tempWindow.subviews count]; i++){
keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES){
//Keyboard is now a UIView reference to the UIKeyboard we want. From here we can add a subview
//to th keyboard like a new button
}
}
```

code shamelessly copied from [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/6573-howto-customize-uikeyboard.html) link..Look at it..a very informative thread..

I dont know if any other method out there..Hope it will be useful..

Comment: I think `if([keyboard isKindOfClass:[UIKeyboard class]])` would be nicer.